# Two Column html, how do i move a column?

Tags: css, html, stylesheet

I have two columns, floated left and right, like so:

```
<div style="float: left;">
text1
</div>
<div style="float: right;">
text 2
</div>
```

but how can i move the right column a little bit to the LEFT? with 'padding'? how to?

or if i use this, how can i move the column on the right it a little bit to the RIGHT?

```
<div style="float: left;">
text1
</div>
<div style="float: left;">
text 2
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change the css style to do it try the following

```
<div style="float: left; position: relative; left: 30px">
```

This changes the positioning to relative and then you move the box based on what it's original position was.

Comment: +1 good, but just to point out to the OP, you should definitely put your CSS in its own file, or at least in a separate `style` tag.

Comment: Thank you but should I make the column on the right float 'left' or 'right'?

I know how to do it both ways now but just want to know the right way

Answer (score 0):

You can try this instead:

```
<div style="float:left; padding-right:-30px;">
```

or

```
<div style="float:left; padding-right:30px;">
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: i'll try that....but this seems to work too, is it right?

    <div style="float: left;">text1</div>
    <div style="float: right; position: relative; left: -80px">text</div>

thats the whole code, is it right?